# React: componentDidMount + setState not re-rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and struggle to update a custom component using `componentDidMount` and `setState`, which seems to be the recommended way of doing it. Below an example (includes an `axios` API call to get the data):

```
import React from 'react';
import {MyComponent} from 'my_component';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    GetData() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/<route>');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.GetData().then(
                (resp) => {
                    this.setState(
                        {data: resp.data}
                    )
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponent data={this.state.data} />
        );
  } 
}
```

Doing `console.log(this.state.data)` just below `render()` shows that `this.state.data` does indeed get updated (from `[]` to whatever the API returns). However, the problem appears to be that `MyComponent` isn't rendered afresh by `componentDidMount`. From the Facebook react docs:

> Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

This does not seem to be the case here: The constructor of `MyComponent` only gets called once (where `this.props.data = []`) and the component does not get rendered again. I'd be great if someone could explain why this is and whether there's a solution or a different way altogether to get the updating done.

**UPDATE**

I've added the code for `MyComponent` (minus some irrelevant features, as indicated by `...`). `console.log(data_array)` prints an empty array.

```
import React from 'react';

class DataWrapper {
  constructor(data) {
    this._data = data;
  }

  getSize() {
    return this._data.length;
  }

     ...
}


export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._dataWrapper = new DataWrapper(this.props.data);

        this.state = {
          data_array: this._dataWrapper,
        };

      }

    render() {
        var {data_array} = this.state;
        console.log(data_array);
        return (
                ...
        );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `MyComponent`? What you're doing in the container component looks right, but something weird might be happening inside the child component.

Comment: The constructor doesn't have to get called more than once. React has already created the object, it doesn't have to do it again. If you log something out in `componentWillReceiveProps`, you'll see that working fine. And if MyComponent renders out something in `this.props.data`, then that will be updated.

Comment: Yea, why does constructor need to be called again? Try putting a console.log in the render to confirm that it renders twice.

Comment: Have you checked if the `this` in your "then" arrow function really points to the React class?

Comment: I've added the code for `MyComponent` to the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are falling victim to [this antipattern.](https://github.com/vjeux/react-website/blob/master/src/react/content/tips/10-props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.md)

In `MyComponent` constructor, which only gets called the first time it mounts, passed your empty array through `new DataWrapper` and now you have some local state which will never be updated no matter what your parent does.

It's always better to have one source of truth, just one state object anywhere (especially for things like ajax responses), and pass those around via props. In fact this way, you can even write `MyComponent` as a simple function, instead of a class.

```
class Example extends Component {
  state = { data: [] }

  GetData() { .. }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetData().then(res =>
      this.setState({data: new DataWrapper(res.data)})
    )
  }

  render() { return <MyComponent data={this.state.data} /> }
}

...

function MyComponent (props) {
  // props.data will update when your parent calls setState
  // you can also call DataWrapper here if you need MyComponent specific wrapper
  return (
    <div>..</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @julestruong  The article is precisely about OP's issue, which part are you unclear about? (setting state from incoming props)

Answer (score 0):

In other words what azium is saying, is that you need to turn your receiving component into a controlled one. Meaning, **it shouldn't have state at all**. Use the props directly.

Yes, even turn it into a functional component. This helps you maintain in your mind that functional components generally don't have state (it's possible to put state in them but ... seperation of concerns).

If you need to edit state from that controlled component, provide the functions through props and define the functions in the "master" component. So the master component simply lends control to the children. They want anything they talk to the parent.

I'm not posting code here since the ammendment you need to make is negligible. Where you have this.state in the controlled component, change to this.props.